# Boost - cross checking i did this right (Windows)

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin

I have cygwin up and running (compiled and ran sample code. no problem).

I downloaded boost here:
`C:\cygwin\lib\boost_1_53_0`

and ran bootstrap.sh (ran no problem).

I ran:
`$ ./b2 install --prefix=../boost`

when I was in `./lib/boost_1_53_0` assuming it would install to `./lib`

and now indeed I have:
`C:\cygwin\lib\boost`

and I am trying to compile and run:

```
        #include<iostream>
        #include<boost/any.hpp>

        int main()
        {
        boost::any a(5);
        a = 7.67;
        std::cout<<boost::any_cast<double>(a)<<std::endl;
        }
```

which is located in `./home/usr/` and I get this:

```
        Jason@ITHAKA-DB44CFE1 /home/jason
        $  g++  -o first first.cpp
        first.cpp:2:24: boost/any.hpp: No such file or directory
        first.cpp: In function `int main()':
        first.cpp:6: error: `boost' has not been declared
        first.cpp:6: error: `any' undeclared (first use this function)
        first.cpp:6: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)
        first.cpp:6: error: expected `;' before "a"
        first.cpp:7: error: `a' undeclared (first use this function)
        first.cpp:8: error: `boost' has not been declared
        first.cpp:8: error: `any_cast' undeclared (first use this function)
        first.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before "double"
        first.cpp:8: error: expected `;' before "double"
        first.cpp:9:2: warning: no newline at end of file

        Jason@ITHAKA-DB44CFE1 /home/jason
        $
```

I am giving as many details as I can to solve this, but I am not sure why this is happening. Should boost be --prefix'd somewhere else?

The path to any.hpp is: `C:\cygwin\lib\boost\include\boost\any.hpp`

the result to `$  g++ -v -o first first.cpp` is:

```
            Jason@ITHAKA-DB44CFE1 /home/jason
            $  g++ -v -o first first.cpp
            Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/specs
            Configured with: /managed/gcc-build/final-v3-bootstrap/gcc-3.4.4-999/configure --verbose --program-suffix=-3 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc --libdir=/usr/lib --libexecdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,d,f77,pascal,java,objc --enable-nls --without-included-gettext --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --without-x --enable-libgcj --disable-java-awt --with-system-zlib --enable-interpreter --disable-libgcj-debug --enable-threads=posix --enable-java-gc=boehm --disable-win32-registry --enable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
            Thread model: posix
            gcc version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125)
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -D__CYGWIN32__ -D__CYGWIN__ -Dunix -D__unix__ -D__unix -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/lib/../../include/w32api first.cpp -quiet -dumpbase first.cpp -mtune=pentiumpro -auxbase first -version -o /tmp/ccNdgnCA.s
            ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
            ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/include"
            ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/lib/../../include/w32api"
            #include "..." search starts here:
            #include <...> search starts here:
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/i686-pc-cygwin
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include/c++/backward
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/include
             /usr/include
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../include/w32api
            End of search list.
            GNU C++ version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125) (i686-pc-cygwin)
                    compiled by GNU C version 3.4.4 (cygming special, gdc 0.12, using dmd 0.125).
            GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
            first.cpp:7:2: warning: no newline at end of file
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/as.exe -o /tmp/ccCB9HBt.o /tmp/ccNdgnCA.s
             /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/collect2.exe -Bdynamic --dll-search-prefix=cyg -o first.exe /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../../crt0.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/3.4.4/../../.. /tmp/ccCB9HBt.o -lstdc++ -lgcc -lcygwin -luser32 -lkernel32 -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -lgcc
```

Comment: What if you add something like "-IC:\cygwin\lib\boost\include\" to the compile line? I'm not sure how to reference that directory correctly, but it should be something like that.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to know is if boost is installed in the right place? I would rather install it to the proper location than need to reference it always in this way.

Comment: Ah. If you run `g++` with the `-v` flag, it should tell you where it searches for header files.

Comment: i added the `g++ -v` is in the question. could you please help to advise?

Comment: You need to tell it to compile something to get it to print stuff out. So, try to compile your `first.cpp` file, but add the `-v` flag.

Comment: done please see above

Comment: Well, if you read what you just pasted, you should have all the information you need.

Comment: I did but I do not have a usr/lib path. Should I create this and --prefix boost into it? These are baby steps for me a helping hand is appreciated.

Comment: You can access the `/usr/include` directory from Windows at `C:\cygwin\usr\include`. That's probably where you want to install boost.

Comment: but if i `./b2 install --prefix=/usr/include` i do not see a new folder in `C:\cygwin\usr\include`. i am installing from cygwin obvously.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28975/discussion-between-jason-m-and-xymostech)